# How do I change sections in HTML without getting '#' in the Link?

Tags: html

## Hi

So, while making a website I noticed that when I am redirecting between sections in HTML using 'a' tag I am getting the link as *'www.example.com#section'*.'

This is the code:

```
<a href="#section">Change Section</a>
<section class="section">
 <p> Hi </p>
</section>
```

I want the link as *'www.example.com/section'*

I wanna know how to do this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just how URLs work.

- `https://` determines how to ask for the resource
- `www.example.com` determines what server to ask for it from
- `/some/path/?query=optional` determines what to ask the server for
- `#fragment` is handled client-side and determines where the browser scrolls to on the page

There isn't a sensible way to make the part of the URL that is sent to the server be treated as the part the browser uses to determine where to scroll to.

---

If you want to head down routes that are not sensible…

1. Make the server-side code deliver the same HTML document for every `/path` you want to represent a part of the same page
2. Mark the primary URL as [canonical](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls)
3. Add some client-side JS that:

   1. waits for the [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)
   2. Reads the [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) to get the path
   3. Uses some internal logic to determine what element to scroll to
   4. Uses [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) to scroll to it/Element/scrollTo
4. Add some more client-side JS that:

   1. Listens for click events on your internal links
   2. uses [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) and [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to change the URL without leaving the current (identical) page
   3. Reads the URL from the `href` of the clicked link
   4. Does the same as steps 3.3 and 3.4
5. Add some more client-side JS that

   1. listens for [popstate events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event)
   2. gets the URL the user is going back to
   3. Does the same as steps 3.3 and 3.4

… now that's a lot of work to make URLs act in a non-standard way.